# The best way to create drop down menu in android 2.x like in ICS

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, drop-down-menu, popupmenu

I want to create button with drop down menu, like overflow menu button in ActionBar on ICS. I have problem because PopupMenu there isn't in android 2.x. The second way using Spinner but it's not for me, because Spinner always show the first item on my custom background or my selected item. How can I acheive it? In general, I want ContextMenu but little and on position clicked view. Thanks.

It looks like this :
[image: Overflow menu in right top corner]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your purpose is to recreate an action bar, you could take a look at the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) project, which backports thoses functionalities.

If you want to be able to pop such a menu anywhere in your app, you could read the implementation of the [MenuPopupHelper](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.java) class implementation in the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) project source code.

Comment: Ok. I think the best answer is your. But I decided that I will use just context menu because I dont see simple way to use popupMenu.

Answer (score 3):

I use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for that sort of thing.  It's more work than a PopupMenu, where you just give it a Menu and respond to events with `OnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick()`.  With a PopupWindow, you provide a content View and handle clicks at a somewhat lower level.

Still, it gets the job done without too much trouble.  The `showAsDropDown()` method allows you to anchor the popup to another View (position it appropriately as a drop-down or pop-up menu), just as you want.  It's been around since API level 1 and works great for me on all my test devices.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your requirement could be ,that you create a list view,, position it under your button & set it's visibility to invisible by default & when you click on the button you can toggle the listview's visibility ....
for example

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (LISTVIEW.isShown()) {
                    LISTVIEW.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    LISTVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

let me know if this helps...

Comment: Thats a great way to do it. Can you control where the ListView is placed?

Comment: You can position it wherever you wish to ,but I guess you'll need to hardcode its dimensions.