# How to create the Action Overflow part of the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been looking online for a while, and there are very little tutorials on how to do this. Even the google docs have very vague info on how to put this stuff up there! I am sure its subtle, but I can't understand the terminology because I am still fairly new to Android. I would like to be able to get the Action Overflow icon to the right side of the `ActionBar`. Putting the view control was pretty understandable using the docs and example code when creating a project, but it does not have one for the Action Overflow. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I should probably elaborate. I would like the menus to default being under the action overflow. I found an eye opener answer to a similar question, but it only tells you how to put the menus at the top. How can I force them to go under the list? Is it even possible to force that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use API-11, it's not problem. If lower I am inviting you to this topic :
[The best way to create drop down menu in android 2.x like in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274174/the-best-way-to-create-drop-down-menu-in-android-2-x-like-in-ics)

In the case when API-11 and higher you must :

1. Create menu xml like this :

   ```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

           <item
               android:id="@+id/item_refresh"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
               android:title="Refresh"
               android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/item_save"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
               android:title="Save"
               android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
       </menu>
   ```

And create code like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // gets the activity's default ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //inflate our menu
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item_refresh:
        //click on refresh item
        break;
    case R.id.item_save:
        //click on save item
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Nope, its 15! So how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Just ran what you gave me in various different ways. None of accomplished what I need :/ It puts them up there all right, but its doesn't make them into action overflows.

Comment: Wait, does it matter if I am running it on an emulator rather than on a device?

Comment: Nope, not working. I am tweaking the Android example that it automakes for you when creating a project with what you just said. Not creating a spinner like effect to the menus when they can't be shown since thats the action overflow look and feel.

Comment: Ok. You see ActionBar and one has menu button. You click it and overflow menu is shown or after click do nothing? Where is problem?

Comment: No, the Action Overflow menu in the top right is not showing. The menus are shown at the top i there is room. Otherwise I need to press menu to have the rest show up. I want all the extras to show up in the Action Overflow menu on the top right

Comment: Damn, I finally had a chance to test it on an actual device, and it seems like it does matter if you do it on a emulator or a device. On the emulator it doesn't put the Action Overflow design at the top automatically, but on a device it does. So I guess it solves my problem in that manner. Thank you.