# Hiding of the Toast for long press on actionBar item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, toast, long-press

Is some possible way how to hide the toast after long-press on the ActionBar item? I didn't setup a title for the item but it is still there - empty toast.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_dots"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_icons_dots"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_my_profile"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/ab_my_profile">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_settings"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_help"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/tv_help_login">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_about_us"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/ab_about_us">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_logout"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/bt_logout_main">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: He's talking about the toast that pops up automatically when you long-press an item on the ActionBar. This is something the ActionBar does, it's not part of his code.

Comment: But I mean Toast when you long-press the ActionBar item. I know that you can cancel ordinary Toast, this is not my problem.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mimic the overflow menu. Why not just use the actual overflow menu?

Comment: It is because I need "three dots" picture for all phones (overflow menu eveytime on action bar). In the case that you have hard context button the "three dots" picture isn't there.

Comment: If you are referring to older devices, two things worth mentioning: 1) ActionBarSherlock library makes ActionBar accessible on older devices, and you will still get your 3 dots menu. 2) If the user has an older device and they are accustomed to using the hardware menu key, let them.

Comment: Yes, I am using ActionBarSherlock but the "three dots" item has to be like this - it is in my project description from customer. But still there is a problem with empty toast after long-press and it seems that there is no solution :/

Comment: This is a feature of the native action bar. It cannot be removed.

Comment: @AdaMoOo don't forgot guidelines. If you do this it will violate the action bar design guidelines

Comment: The better way to solve is: not solve, give title for items and let Android deal with the items, they can be displayed as a overflow in some devices and a title label does help the user to do things.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274174/the-best-way-to-create-drop-down-menu-in-android-2-x-like-in-ics) question, I am pretty sure you want to achieve that.

Comment: This is like welding your car doors shut: you welded the doors shut but ruined the usability of the car in doing so (devaluing it a lot). Just add the text, let it show, it is there for a reason (hinting as to what the purpose of the action is).

Answer (score 6):

The only way to hide the toast is when you set the `ActionBar` menu item to be displayed with text. `android:showAsAction="withText"`. Otherwise the toast adds clarification of what each action item represents even if there is no title set for menu item.

Comment: Hello do you have any idea of how the text can be added to the toast if one wants to

Comment: I want to add some text in the toast that is shown on long press

Comment: Doesn't work  you are talking about adding this to <item nodes>

Comment: The toast message which is shown after long press on menu item is the text which you are setting to it using `android:text=""`. if you want to show another text different from that, I don't think this is possible at all, as far as I know.

Comment: hey its not text but the title `android:title=""`

Comment: Sorry my bad, but that's the only text which you can put in menuItem.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the cleanest way to go about this is to assign a custom action view to your menu item that mimics the look of a regular one.

Since you mentioned you're using ActionBarSherlock, here's a simple example.

Imagine the following **menu.xml**, which gets inflated in an `Activity`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ab_main_menu_dots"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/ab_main_menu_dots_layout"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

You can define **ab_main_menu_dots_layout.xml** to mimic the overflow button like this:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The result is a menu item that looks like an overflow button and does not display a `Toast` message when you long-press it, regardless of whether the native ActionBar is used or ABS. Up to you to take it from here. You want to reconsider and abide by the guidelines instead.

Comment: Hey @MH... My  requirement is  just opposite it. I want toast on my custom action layout item. How to achieve this.

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal: I guess you could just show a toast in the action item's on(long)click. Toasts can be fully customised and displayed anywhere on the screen, so you should be able to just replicate the default toast behaviour (hint: just take a peak in the framework's source code).

Comment: :Thanks for suggestion, and yeah(hint: just take a peak in the framework's source code) is a great hint (& tip as well) for newbie developers like me.Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify `onLongClick`in [ActionMenuItemView](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java) Class to stop Toasting on long click.
but be careful, It's only working on devices with API less than 11, because sherlockactionbar library checking your device API level by `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and if you have newer device it just use default system actionbar which you're not modifying.

Answer (score 5):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` schedule a task to **disable** **long click** on desired menu item. Here is the sample

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View v = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_menu_item);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's dirty, it's working, it's dirty working ! Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.no_toast);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.custom_view);
    item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //handle click (just this item)
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

and this is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="Never gonna see me in a toast!"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:id="@+id/no_toast" />
</menu>
```

my custom view is just an `ImageButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

**Note:** don't forget to set style, `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation` makes `IamgeButton` to be shown correctly in toolbar.

**P.S:** Personally I prefer the default behavior but this was my case:
 I disabled right to left support for my application and after that when I set default locale to a *rtl* language, toast was showing up in the wrong side! Honestly I was in hurry and didn't find out the reason but I'll appreciate if someone let me know the why, anyway this is how I passed through.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using custom action view as follow:

```
action_menu.xml
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        support:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

</menu>

custom_action_view.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/customActionItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/bulb_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and menu inflater code is as follow:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);     

        final MenuItem item1= menu.findItem(R.id.item1);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item1, R.layout.custom_action_view);
        View vItem1= MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item1);

        final ImageButton customActionItem= (ImageButton) vItem1.findViewById(R.id.customActionItem);
        customActionItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // do something here
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the toast for an action view?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own custom `ActionBar`. Here is a tutorial on how to do that:
[Custom Action Bar](http://www.rqgg.net/topic/kxnm-how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was using:

```
android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
```

So instead of inflating the menu from the XML:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.refresh_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I created the items programmatically using MenuItemCompat:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem refreshItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.menu_item_refresh, Menu.NONE, R.string.general_pop_up_dialog_btn_cancel);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(refreshItem, R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_refresh);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(refreshItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a way, if you're using ActionBarSherlock. Find the ActionMenuItemView.java file in library and just comment whole onLongClick method.