# Android ActionBar design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to show a item from left first. Like this

[image]

So, I tried this

```
<item android:id="@+id/refresh" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="Refresh" 
    android:visible="true">
</item>
```

But, It show the item from right. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Can you post the details of the layout this item is a child of?

Comment: I don't think `android:layout_gravity` is a valid attribute for a menu item.

Comment: The only way to accomplish that in an ActionBar is to use a custom view (and hide the icon etc.). Basically your menu items will become a bunch of, say, `ImageView`s that are styled like action items. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17735176/1029225).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. That place is reserved for the app icon and view control, the options menu come 3d in line, and they appear in the right side of the `ActionBar`.

Here's the general organization of the `ActionBar`: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#organization