# How to Disable Menu Item Long click listener in Toolbar

Tags: android, dialog, toolbar

Am using Toolbar (v21) in dialog which is working correctly. But when I am longpressing the menu item in toolbar, the default Toast (which shows menu item's title) is showing on orginal position of action bar.

Just disabling longpress event of menu item would be good for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408365/hiding-of-the-toast-for-long-press-on-actionbar-item) may help you to handle Long Click Listener on Toolbar.

Please add your comments if it is helpful.

Comment: I think its a default behavior of option menu. There is no way to disable it. It is good to see toast on long click, when user don't know that what specific menu icon dose. :)